# Short help and long help in commander

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, node-commander

I am using [commander](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander) package as CLI parser.

```
   commander
      .command('command1 <parameter>' )
      .description('description 1 goes here')
      .command('command2 <parameter>' )
      .description('description 2 goes here')
```

Is there a way to display short descriptions when global help command is called, e.g.

```
myprogram help

# Commands:
#  command1 <parameter>  description 1 goes here
#  command2 <parameter>  description 2 goes here
```

but also have ability to show expanded help when help for specific command is called:

```
myprogram help command1

# command1 is used for...
#
# ... detailed description
#
# ...
```

Comment: Raised and answered in GitHub home project: https://github.com/tj/commander.js/issues/1506

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out with package's author help. `.description()` can be used to add short inline description shown only on general `help` command, while `.addHelpText()`can include additional help test shown on command-specific help, e.g.

```
  commander
    .command('hello')
    .description('Shows greetings')
    .addHelpText('after', '\nGreets the world ....< long text goes here >')
```